# How to enable Azure Mobile App Authentication by Email/Password (Custom) and Facebook

Tags: facebook, email, azure, authentication, azure-app-service-plans

We're trying to sign-up new users to our App - using either Facebook or Email/Password. (A very typical situation )

Facebook Auth is easy & Built in.
Auth by Email/Pass - now seems to be not supported (See Below)

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-authentication-overview/

How is this done?

I see Azure Active Directory Auth is Built-in ...Is MS suggesting we use Active Directory for Email/Pass Sign-ups?

Thanks

Comment: we have exact same requirements can you please tell what did you do?

Answer (score 0):

In the link that you referenced, there is a section titled "Do-it-yourself authentication" with links to starting points for rolling your custom authentication. So Email/Pass authentication is STILL supported.

What is not supported is side-by-side custom authentication and using the gateway authentication that you get with Facebook/Azure AD/Google/etc.

So yes... if you want to use the gateway authentication... use Azure AD. If you want to roll your own, you own it all. If you choose to roll your own, you can still use the FB/Google/OAuth, but you will be coding and configuring on your own, not in the portal identity setup.